# JQM apply overlay-theme popup style on silde Panel

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a stylistic problem with jquery mobile,
i want reproduce the data-overlay-theme="a" of popup :

> Sets the color scheme (swatch) for the popup background, which covers
>   the entire window. If not explicitly set, the background will be
>   transparent.
>   http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html

for a slide Panels... 
I try with this code, but I think need a css edit.

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-theme="b" data-display="overlay" data-overlay-theme="a">
```

can someone help me with an example?
thanks !

Comment: In code, for slide panels, there are only `data-theme` and `data-track-theme` options, nothing else.

Comment: can edit the css file to emulate data-overlat-theme effects?

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to add this to JS code (not css). You can change current theme in `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css` file. In fact I think that you can change specyfic styles adding eg. `html body #mypanel {color: red;}`. Use Opera dragonfly or firebug (ctrl+shift+i) to obtain structure of elements...